# how to build Executable jar to return string to shell script

Tags: java, shell, return-value, executable-jar, return-type

I have to run executable jar file from shell script to get a string value. The executable jar can't return a value as the main returns void. I can't use System.exit(int) as jar has to return value of String type.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

This data should be written to stdout (`System.out` in Java), and captured with `$(command expansion)`.

Here's what all good Unix citizens (and far too few Java programs) make sure to do:

- Write program result to stdout (System.out)
- Write error messages and debugging to stderr (System.err)
- Use `System.exit(0)` to indicate success (this is also the default if no System.exit is used)
- Use `System.exit(1)` (or higher, up to 255) to indicate failure

Here's a complete example for demonstrating the interplay between Java and shell scripts:

```
$ cat Foo.java
class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This data should be captured");
    System.err.println("This is other unrelated data.");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

A very basic manifest:

```
$ cat manifest
Main-Class: Foo
```

A simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if var=$(java -jar foo.jar)
then
  echo "The program exited with success."
  echo "Here's what it said: $var"
else
  echo "The program failed with System.exit($?)"
  echo "Look at the errors above. The failing output was: $var"
fi
```

Now let's compile and build the jar and make the script executable:

```
$ javac Foo.java
$ jar cfm foo.jar manifest Foo.class
$ chmod +x myscript
```

And now to run it:

```
$ ./myscript
This is other unrelated data.
The program exited with success.
Here's what it said: This data should be captured
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run a Java application that will launch a shell and capture the string from that? I am thinking of many applications which capture username / password from a shell.  For example if using spring check out:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell

Comment: The application needs to return the value to shell script. So from shell script I have to run the jar and catch the returned string value.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Try to write your String to System.stdout and read it from there. Maybe you can write output to a file and read it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion : Get the java application to save its output to a temporary file and then get the shell script to read in the contents of the file such as VAR=`cat /tmp/temp_file`